# Run each hotkey in a script file in a separate thread (with max threads per hotkey = 1)

Tags: autohotkey

I have a `.ahk` script file with 3 hotkeys.

Each hotkey takes a few seconds to complete.

What happens when I run hotkey `a` and then hotkey `b` before `a` is finished is that `a` is interrupted and the script continues with `b`.

Basically I want `a` and `b` to run concurrently.

Can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True Multi-Threading in a single script does not exist (yet) in AutoHotkey.

While there are some ways to try and create "fake" multithreading, the best solution at the present is to have each hotkey run their own separate ahk script files using the [`Run`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) command.

---

Hope this was helpful; if you would like an example of what this kind of code would look like, lmk and I can go ahead and create one.

Answer (score 1):

When I need two functions to operate simultaneously I make multiple scripts that interact with each other. Unfortunately Autohotkey doesn't support multi-threading so that's the only way to do it.

**Some ideas:**

- You can pass variables between scripts using msgbox and/or GUIs.
- You can also use msgbox as a "wait until" if you need one function to
  wait for the other to complete a part of automation.
- I sometimes use that to make two scripts "play tag" to utilize all
  the down time that exists during load times on websites. In other
  words, I make two bots that interact with separate websites...
  automating one while the other one is waiting for its page to load.
- I have also utilized a "control panel" type of setup where I make a
  master script that controls subroutines (other scripts) via GUIs. You
  can then use the buttons to trigger Run commands and provide kill
  buttons for each subroutine. This will give it the feeling of a full
  application if you do it all through controlsend to a hidden gui. The
  master script can then keep track of all the variables that need to
  be exchanged between subroutines with msgbox like I mentioned before.
  But I think at that point you might want to just incorporate another
  more powerful language like python or Java.